# Float: left seems doesn't work

Tags: css

I have this [site](http://www.canalonesbastimar.com). Since I have `float: left` in "Instalacion de canalon en Madrid", I expected "2 años" be on the right of "Instalacion de canalon en Madrid" but no, anyone knows why?

```
.logo-h1 {
  float: left;
  .logo {
    width: 324px;
    height: 57px;
    a {
      width: 324px;
      height: 57px;
      display: block;
    }
  }
  h1 {
    font-size: 17px;
    font-family: Verdana, Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;
    width: 491px;
    margin-left: 20px;
    color: #BC2758;
    margin-top: 6px;
  }
}
.garantia {
  margin: 9px 24px 0 0;
  width: 145px;
  height: 91px;
}
```

Comment: Please add meaningful code and a problem description here. Don't just link 
to the site that needs fixing - otherwise, this question will lose any value
to future visitors once the problem is solved. Posting a 
[Short, Self Contained, Correct Example (SSCCE)](http://www.sscce.org/) 
that demonstrates your problem would help you get better answers. For more info, 
see [Something on my web site doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to
it?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125997/) Thanks!

Comment: Almost 5k reputation, and nothing but a LINK

Comment: sorry!! Now there is the code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Float` removes the element from the normal HTML flow. When you have multiple elements, you need to give each one a `float` attribute. In this case, you can also give `float:left` to your `div` with `class="garantia my-icons-garantia"` (2 anos), and it will appear to the right of the first one.

Comment: thanks, but why it works here? http://codepen.io/anon/pen/wFklj What is the difference with my code?

Comment: In your code, the `float` is on the `div` parent to `h1`. In fact, both the title and the "2 anos" are in a `div` so that's why you need a `float:left` on both.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure why that is happening, but if you add `float: left` to "2 anos", it will appear to the right of "Instalacion de cananlon en Madrid"